# Eclipse plugin : Inactivate functionality when testing

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an eclipse plugin.
I'd like to inactivate some functionalities when i test my plugin (Run As > Eclipse application). And activate these same functionalities when the plugin is 'really" use.

I'm wondering if i can detect the "launching context" (test or not).
Otherwise i was thinkink about using a VM propety or application property.

Do you have any good idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to detect a test launch.

I would use a program argument, use:

```
String [] args = Platform.getApplicationArgs();
```

to get the arguments in a plugin.

Or if you have the `IApplicationContext` use:

```
String [] args = (String [])applicationContext.getArguments().get(IApplicationContext.APPLICATION_ARGS);
```

Comment: The default workspace when you "Run As" is "runtime-EclipseApplication". It's not a perfect solution but i can use this piece of infromation for toogling feature. Thanks also for your solution greg-449. But unfortunatly it needs user manual action (setting the program argument)

Answer (score 0):

I'd be curious to know more of your use case - as I think usually it is the other way around, i.e.:

- Functionalities are added in development/testing environment (for debugging purpose, or work-in-progress).
- Those are hidden/disabled/not shipped when the plug-in is packaged/deployed.

Also giving more details on the functionalities you want to disable (code only, code and extension, extension only, etc.) could help proposing an adequate solution to your problem.

Anyway, you could split your plug-in in 2 (one with the functionalities you want to enable and the other for the ones you don't want), then filter the unwanted plug-in from the launch configuration you run to test your application. Something like this:

- Refactor your plug-in.
- Edit the launch configuration used to run your eclipse application (Click 'Run' -> 'Run Configurations...'), then select your launch configuration in the 'Eclipse Application' category.
- Select the 'Plug-ins' tab, then set the value of the 'Launch with' combo-box to 'plug-ins selected below only'.

[image: Plug-ins tab for Eclipse Application Launch Configuration]

- Find the plug-in you want to disable in the 'Plug-ins' table and un-check it.
- Then click apply and run.